# What is `values` in firefox web console?

Tags: javascript, web, firefox, console

I was playing around firefox web console before I encountered this strange behaviour. I cannot recall `window.values` or sth from web standard, and it is not a website-specific, so I guess it must be from the web console itself:

[image: the values]

But what is it and what is it for, and where can I find a document for that ?

Comment: It also exists in Chrome.

Comment: It appears to be equivalent to `Object.values()`.

Comment: @Barmar and it seems also return the `length` when the arg is an `array` or a `string`

Comment: I guess it's including the `.length` property. Chrome doesn't do that. It doesn't return anything for a string, and only the array elements for an array.

Comment: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers) is a list of all the helpers, or you can type `help()` in your firefox console to get to the same page :-). You'll find `values()` described there